# Nested Cauchy type integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function which is in integral form:

$$f_+(z)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{f(\alpha)}{(z-\alpha)}\,d\alpha\bigg),$$

where $C$ is a unit circle. I want to take the Fourier transform of this function, that is,

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_Cf_{+}(z)z^{x-1}\,dz,$$

where again $C$ is a unit circle. The function $f(z)$ has a complicated expression:$$f(z)=\log(\lambda(z)),$$ with 
$$\lambda(z)=\frac{r(z)-h(z)}{r(z)+h(z)},$$ where $$r(z)=\sqrt{q(z)+2},~h(z)=\sqrt{q(z)-2},$$ and $$q(z)=4-z-z^{-1}-\omega^2,$$ with $\omega=\omega_1+i\omega_2$, $\omega_1\in(0,2)$ and $\omega_2\ll1$, $\omega_2>0$.

I am trying to do this using NIntegrate but I am not successful. Can anybody please give a hint or help to do this type of nested integration in Mathematica?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $F(x)$ the Fourier transform of $f_+(z)$ in fact?

Comment: @user64494 yes it is.

Comment: Why do you think so? Look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform .

Comment: @user64494 it is an inverse of discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: Can you kindly give an accessible reference? I don't find that formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform .

Comment: A right place for such type questions is https://math.stackexchange.com . I suggest to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @user64494 You can find the definition in this book

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Theory_and_application_of_the_z_transfor.html?id=NwFRAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y

There is another book: https://books.google.co.in/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Difference_Equations.html?id=RmRxcgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, both the books are not instantly accessible to me. Indeed up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform, $F(x)$ can be treated as  the inverse $Z$-transform of $f_+(z)$ with integer $x$. Under some assumption on $f(\alpha)$, $F(x)$ should be equal to zero for $x\in \mathbb{N}$. All that is empty talk without any knowledge about $f(\alpha)$ and off-topic.

Comment: @user64494 I hope this edit would make things more clear.

Comment: I'd like to add that for $\alpha \in C$  the value of  should be defined as the limit of $f_+(\xi)$ as $\xi \to \alpha$ or the integral which defines $f_+$ should be treated as its principal value. There is an option in NIntegrate to this end.

Comment: @user64494 The imaginary part in $\omega$ makes the integral well defined.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.

Comment: @user64494 If you do the integral on a unit circle it would give you a finite number when $\omega$ is complex number with $\omega_2\sim10^{-2}$ or so.

Comment: You are not right. In any case, the integral $$ \oint_{C}\frac{f(\alpha)}{(z-\alpha)}\,d\alpha$$ is improper if $z \in C$.